# What minimal Spring Boot 2.x version can run for sure on Java 17?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependencies, version

Can Spring Boot 3.0 requires at least Java 17.

**What minimal Spring 2.x version can run for sure on Java 17?**

Java 17 was released 14 Sep 2021 https://endoflife.date/java
so I would expect Spring Boot 2.6 (released 19 Nov 2021) https://endoflife.date/spring-boot
to be for sure tested against JRE 17.

Where is it possible to see min and max supported Java (JRE) version for every Spring Boot version?

Comment: Try Spring official documentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Boot [2.5 is minimal version that supports JRE 17 according to documnetation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements).

([2.4 was intially up to JRE 16](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements))
UPDATE as @spamove commented,

> 2.4.2+ runs with JRE 17 without any real apparent issues

So if you are to upgrade you old project to run on JRE 17, be sure to upgrade to at least 2.5 version.
( But I would recommend the last 2.x which is 2.7,
that will be supported even for longer time than 3.0 )

Also see Spring framework Java version requirement
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions

[image]

Comment: TBH, while that answers the OP's question as asked ("... can run _for sure_ on Java 17"), that's not entirely true. Spring Boot 2.5 is the minimal version that _officially_ supports JRE 17. Actual real world trial shows that, while Spring Boot 2.4.1 is indeed incompatible with JRE 17, any Spring Boot >= 2.4.2 runs with JRE 17 without any real apparent issues. I'm not saying that it means that it's a good idea to do so, but still in some cases it might be helpful to know that (e.g. when you can't bump the dep due to compat. issues, but can still bump the JRE)

Answer (score 4):

Any version of Spring docs has a dedicated section about this:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements

Comment: thanks for hint, but exact answer is v2.5