# Maven JLink plugin error `Unsupported class file major version 61`

Tags: java, maven, jlink

Running the Maven JLink plugin I get an error `Unsupported class file major version 61`.

I'm using the BellSoft Liberica 17 Full JDK for the project. The JRE for the Maven runner is set to 'Use Project JDK', so it should be the same. I use the Maven plugins underneath:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>17</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Both plugins are the latest versions. I probably need some more configurations for the JLink plugin, but would first like to resolve this error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Already read these: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442835/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-with-java-17-and-spring-framework-2-2-4), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425829/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-error), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72227442/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272445/java-17-maven-doesnt-give-much-information-about-the-error-that-happened-why).

This is `mvn --version` output:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.2 (c9616018c7a021c1c39be70fb2843d6f5f9b8a1c)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 17.0.8, vendor: BellSoft, runtime: C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJDK-17-Full
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

These are the logs including stacktrace:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< io.wouter.gmsbooks:gms-offers-v9 >------------------
[INFO] Building gms-offers-v9 1.2.0
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] -------------------------------[ jlink ]--------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ gms-offers-v9 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 11 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ gms-offers-v9 ---
[WARNING] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING] * Required filename-based automodules detected: [jersey-client-3.1.2.jar, jersey-common-3.1.2.jar, jersey-apache-connector-3.1.2.jar, jersey-media-json-jackson-3.1.2.jar, commons-validator-1.7.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
[WARNING] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ gms-offers-v9 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gms-offers-v9 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ gms-offers-v9 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Wouter\Documents\repos\wio\bol\v9\gmsbooks-offer-app\target\surefire-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.758 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-21T17:48:30+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 2 plugin(s)
[WARNING] 
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING] 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project gms-offers-v9: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test failed: Unsupported class file major version 61 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project gms-offers-v9: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test failed: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test failed: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.parse (AsmModuleInfoParser.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.getModuleDescriptor (AsmModuleInfoParser.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager.resolvePaths (LocationManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.newStartupConfigForModularClasspath (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1810)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.createStartupConfiguration (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1753)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.createForkStarter (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:2103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: You'll need to check which version you (maven) is actually using. It should be ok, but there's always a chance for some obscure config to mess it up.

Comment: Please add the full logoutput for the exception you got.....and best would be a working example ...

Comment: Any ideas still?